# Splash screen in ionic framework cordova not working

Tags: ionic-framework

This is my code

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, 500);
    });
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it simply not displayed at all? Is the image not correct...?

Comment: What have you done except this piece of code. What did you put in config.xml?Have you generated your resource files?

Comment: i am using visual studio 15 to develop aap . so in config.xml i have only install splash plugins

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hide the splash screen? If you are, why not set up your splash to be a blank image? Find a high res blank png and run the command `ionic resources --splash` and this will generate your splash image for all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a [Cordova's documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html) or the [documentation on npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-splashscreen): you might need to set some preferences in `config.xml`.

First, the following is not mentioned on the first site but it might solve your problem:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```

Maybe you could also have to change some settings such as disabling autohide (you already hide the splash screen manually when you hide your app so it shouldn't be a problem) :

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

**Note :**

As Joseph Ocasio already mentioned, don't forget either to [generate your resources](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html) with the Ionic CLI.

To generate all (application icons + splash screen images) :

```
ionic resources
```

To generate splash screen images only :

```
ionic resources --splash
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have got already installed the plugin cordova-splash-screen  (cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen --save)

Then check you config.xml file and add this

```
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
```

It should be work :)

Comment: Where do I add this when i click on config.xml it shows me page of configuration ..where should I provide preference